# Problem with subcaption with subfig package

Tags: captions, subcaption, subfig

it's my first question so I hope to present the problem correctly.
I have a problem with subcaption of subfig package: the subcaption is aligned to the left and isn't as wide as the figure. I tried to simplify my document to the essential or setting the caption option with \captionsetup[subfloat]{} but it doesn't work and the result is the same.
I have no idea how to make it work and I don't have much time to try other solution.
I attach the simplify document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}      
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 
\usepackage{indentfirst}                    

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}       
\usepackage{caption}                    
\captionsetup[subfloat]{}
\usepackage{float}      
\usepackage{subfig} 

                        
\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[p]
        %   
        \subfloat[PPL dolomite smithsonite calcite]{\label{2.JPG}} \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{2.JPG}
        %   
        \subfloat[CL galena sfalertie pirite]{\label{2.JPG}} \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{SAL 102_9.JPG}
        %       
        \caption{minerals minerals minerals}
        \label{minerals}
    \end{figure}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of `\subfloat` is as follows:

```
\subfloat[〈listentry〉][〈sub-caption〉]{〈body〉}
```

with

- `〈listentry〉` being the sub caption used in the list of figures (identical to `〈sub-caption〉` if you did not specify a separate `〈listentry〉`),
- `〈sub-caption〉` being the subcaption shown above/below the image/table, and
- `〈body〉` being the image/table itself.

Thus, a compiling MWE would look like the following (I replaced your images with `example-image`):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}      
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 
\usepackage{indentfirst}                    

\usepackage{graphicx}       
\usepackage{caption}                    
\usepackage{float}      
\usepackage{subfig} 

                        
\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[p]
        %   
        \subfloat[PPL dolomite smithsonite calcite]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}\label{1.JPG}} 
        %   
        \subfloat[CL galena sfalertie pirite]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}\label{2.JPG}} 
        %       
        \caption{minerals minerals minerals}
        \label{minerals}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem if you do that with `floatrow`.

Unrelated: if you have a comparatively recent version of latex, you don't have to load `inputenc`: utf8 isnow the default.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \ffigbox{%
        \begin{subfloatrow}%
        \ffigbox{\caption{PPL dolomite smithsonite calcite}\label{a.JPG}}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
        \hfill%
        \ffigbox{\caption{CL galena sfalertie pirite}\label{b.JPG}}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
        \end{subfloatrow}}%
        {\caption{minerals minerals minerals}}
        \label{minerals}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]